# How to add new object by id to mongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection called **Users** which stores user's messages & info. I want to add new objects to existing collection by it's id.

I receive an error 'TypeError: user.insert is not a function' - i guess i missed something....

Here is the method from the controller :

```
UserDataController.prototype.sendMsg = function (userID, messages_data, cb) {

if (userID) { 

    user.findOne({_id: userID},function(err, result){ //Object id=59e5e542a5ba05056c57d847

        // insert to the collection with the object id

        user.insert({_id: userID} ,messages_data,function(err, result){
            if(err) return cb(err);
            return cb(null, result);
        });
    });

  }

 };
```

Here is the result i wish to get :

```
"sentmessages" : [{
    "message_body" : "whatsup", // new object
    "message_subject" : "whatsup",
    "message_date" : "20/01/2017"
  },
  {
   "message_body" : "whatsup", // new object
    "message_subject" : "whatsup",
    "message_date" : "20/01/2017"
  }]
```

The schema looks like that :

```
var sentmessages = new schema({
   message_date: String,
   message_subject : String,
   message_body : String,

});

var UserSchema = new schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  sentmessages :[sentmessages] // here is were i want to add new objects
});
```

Comment: As far as I understood you want to update an existing record (in order to append a message to the user's list of sent messages), not create a new record. In this case why are you using insert instead of update? I think you should take a look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Thanks - i want to add new records... not update... so each insertion will add a new  {
   "message_body" : "whatsup",
    "message_subject" : "whatsup",
    "message_date" : "20/01/2017"
  } object

Comment: Where do you want that object to be added? If you add it in a separate collection, e.g. "sent_messages", then you are really inserting a record (although I don't see the point in doing so, since you're not keeping information about the user who sent the message). If you are adding the message to an existing user record, you're doing a document update.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Thanks - got it - check out my solution - wonder what you think

Comment: Yes, `$push` should do the trick.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Got it... needed to use $push

```
UserDataController.prototype.sendMsg = function (userID, messages_data, cb) 
{

if (userID) {
    var message_fixesd_data = messages_data.sent_messages[0];
        user.update({_id: userID},
            { $push: { sent_messages: {
                message_body : message_fixesd_data.message_body,
                message_subject: message_fixesd_data.message_subject,
                message_date : message_fixesd_data.message_date
             }
        }

            }, function (err, result) {
            if(err)
            {
                return cb(err);
            }
            else
            {

                return cb(true, 'File was save successfully', result);
            }
        });
   }

};
```